Tilde above the word
I would like to put a tilde over the word phrase PPP. I am using OverTilde. It's not working. Tilde is coming only on the middle P. How to solve this issue.

@Nasser, I have been working on some research work following the paper attached herewith. In equation 4 (page 2) last line, you will find c_{\tilde{WWW}}. I need to put this notation in Mathematica. That's why I am trying to figure it out.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.12973.pdf

I am sure the paper used Latex \widetilde for that equation. \tilde in Latex only works on one letter.

I looked this up. In Latex, tilde works also over one letter. To have tilde over more than one letter, you need to use widetilde. Mathematica does not seem to have widetilde, and only tilde.
So you can either use OverBar or use MaTeX package
OverBar[ppp]

Or use
<< MaTeX`
MaTeX["\\widetilde{ppp}", Magnification -> 2]


See also this related question
MMa version of $\LaTeX$'s overtilde doesn't look as expected

It worked. Thank you so much.

As an emergency in case nothing else works. This works for any length of expression but needs a lot of manual parameter adjusting.
x + 3 Overscript[PPPPPPPPP, 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 70, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2 Pi + 0.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.5]], 
    AspectRatio -> 1/10]]

x + 3 Overscript[PPPPPPPPP, 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 70, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 4 Pi + 0.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.5]], 
    AspectRatio -> 1/10]]



Compared with LATEX wide tilde which seems to spread only over three characters.
$\widetilde{PPPPPPPPP}$
